# Can't get GPS Lock on HTC M8

Tags: gps, htc

Currently I have an HTC M8. I bought the AT&T version and converted over to GPE without a hitch.

Lately I've noticed my GPS apps have not been working. So, I did some research and downloaded GPS ToolBox to try and refresh the A-GPS Data. When loaded, I noticed that it would not lock on to any GPS satellites. It could see 15+ (which i think is pretty decent.)

I did a complete restore after making a backup to no avail. I am not sure what could be the problem, is there a best route in order to troubleshoot this?

I can provide further detail if needed.

Comment: Did it work before you ran the Google Play RUU? It could be a ROM problem also, it's hard to pin down to be honest. Try another ROM maybe and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have identified same problem with the stock firmware 4.4.4 even after a factory reset.  This seems to be an issue with the stock ROM.

Other info: I contacted HTC.  First I was told that my phone would be replaced, now I am told it is a known issue and they are working on it.  But I have found very few reports of this problem online.  I would think that it would be affecting a lot more people.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had the same issue! I noticed this occurs when the phone is on the fringe or outside cell tower range in a remote location. The symptoms present, as location reporting becoming very inaccurate and often jumps miles from the actual position. The M8 was purchased mid-December and fully updated to 4.4.4, it seemed there was a serious bug with the way the phone detects and prioritises GPS correlation with respect to other forms of location fixing until....

I did some further research and found the M8 had reverted (after upgrade) to battery saving mode under location sources in settings (some how I had passed over this setting when looking for a fix) which references wifi and cell networks for rough location fixing. After changing the setting to High Accuracy the issue was resolved so to do this choose Settings-->Location-->Location Sources-->Mode & choose from the 3 options and you are good to go.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. If you can not find the answer to your problem you should [ask your own question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Good call Ryan, found the answer and posted my findings.